# JS regex: Alternative for positive / negative lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having issues with the following regex working in Safari and so am having to change how I approach this regex. I need the following regex to only select the text between: `cp1=` and `|`.

For example if I had this string:

`firstName=John|lastName=Smith|cp1=/en-gb/|age=30`

I'd only want to get `/en-gb/` and nothing else.

The following JS works below in all browsers i've tested except for Safari:

```
// if myString = firstName=John|lastName=Smith|cp1=/en-gb/|age=30
let currentCP1Value = myString.match(/(?<=cp1=)(.*)(?=\|)|(?<=cp1=).*(?<!a)$/); // outputs /en-gb/
```

This is due to the positive/negative lookbehind's used in the regex. What would be the alternative to this to get this working in Safari?

Comment: No need for regex: replace `|` with `&` and presto, this is a query argument string and `URLSearchParams` will do this with a zero-typing-related bug surface.

Comment: Why not just use a capture group with match? Your solution seems over complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the pattern you tried:

- This part of the pattern `(.*)(?=\|)` Matches until the end of the line and then backtracks until it can assert a `|` to the right, which can match too much if there are multiple occurrences of `|` following.
- This part of the pattern `|(?<=cp1=).*(?<!a)$` is the second alternative, which also matches until the end of the line and asserts that it does not end with an `a` char, which seems out of place as you want to match `/en-gb/` ending on `/`

You don't need any lookarounds to get `/en-gb/`, you can use a capture group as you are already using in your pattern.

Use a negated character class `[^|]*` to match any character except `|` to not cross matching the next one.

```
\bcp1=([^|]*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yUJjjA/1)

```js
const myString = "firstName=John|lastName=Smith|cp1=/en-gb/|age=30"
let currentCP1Value = myString.match(/\bcp1=([^|]*)/);
if (currentCP1Value) {
  console.log(currentCP1Value[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use regex at all? If your data doesn't contain text that can be interpreted as URL encoded segments, you can simply replace `|` with `&` and now you have a standard query string that JS has built-in parsing for through [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```
const parsed = new URLSearchParams(input.replaceAll(`|`, `&`));
const cp = parsed.get(`cp1`);
// and many utility functions to perform further work
```

and you're done.

Comment: That's not good advice because you don't know whether the values in the string are URL-encoded, but your solution implies it.

Comment: fun fact: URLSearchParams doesn't need them to be, even if URLs themselves do.

Comment: But URLSearchParams will decode things that look like an encoded value, even if they are meant literally.

Comment: ah, yes that is true, I'll add that this answer, and leave it entirely up to the OP to decide whether their data is safe here or not. Because anything that doesn't _need_ regex is almost always better off not using them. (but given what they're showing, I'm pretty sure this started life as a query set already)

Comment: Try things like `"firstName=John|lastName=Smith|cp1=/en+gb/|age=30"`

Comment: I'm all for "why use regex when there is a parser?", but the caveats must be clear.

Comment: Agreed, hence the edit.